# Access Parent Class Object from a child class

Tags: java

I'm creating a connect Four Game with GUI and I got stuck on Restarting the game.  My goal is that when the user presses the Restart Button on MyBoard JPanel the game will restart. I'm using the mouseListener and I want to access the object panel from the child class MyBoard.

```
 public class Mediator(){
      public Mediator(){ 
          MyBoard panel = new MyBoard();
          JFrame board = new JFrame("Connect4");
          board.setSize(728, 728);
          board.setLocationRelativeTo(null); 
          board.add(panel);
          board.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
          board.setVisible(false);
          board.setFocusable(true);
          board.setResizable(false);
      }
}



public class MyBoard extends JPanel implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener {
     public MyBoard( ) {}
           @Override
           public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
               startX = e.getX();
               startY = e.getY();
               //Restart Button
               if (startX > rectButton1.x && startX < rectButton1.x + rectButton1.width && startY > rectButton1.y
                    && startY < rectButton1.y + rectButton1.height) {
            //I'm stuck here  
        }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "restart Mediator"?

Comment: I need to restart the Mediator object on my main method. My main Method is creating an instance of Mediator. I need to restart the JFrame when I the user clicks the button restart.

Comment: `MyBoard` is NOT a child of class Mediator in any way, `MyBoard` does NOT inherit from `Mediator` so it can't be a child of it. `MyBoard` inherits from `JPanel` so `JPanel` is the parent of `MyBoard` not `Mediator`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a reference to Mediator when you create MyBoard

```
public class Mediator(){

    public Mediator(){ 
      MyBoard panel = new MyBoard(this);
      ...


 public class MyBoard extends JPanel implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener {
        private Mediator mediator;

        public MyBoard(Mediator mediator)  {
              this.mediator = mediator;
        ...
```

Also you may have to move the construction of a new board to a method restart instead of doing it in Mediator constructor.

Comment: I hate how you have called Mediator parent as it is not a parent of `MyBoard` in any way.

Comment: @Popeye Ok. No problem. I'll change it.

Comment: @Popeye Mediator creates MyBoard, OP is not talking about inheritance. You don't have to hate us just for interpreting parenthood in a wide way. :-)

Comment: This is why I have not down voted. It's nothing against you it's just how the OP has phrased their question which can create confusion in the question being asked. I read the question initially as being something about inheritance because that is the terminology actually being used in their question. Again nothing against you so I haven't down voted.

Comment: @RubioRic Thanks for explaing your answer it helped me alot. Spend hours trying to figure it out on my own.